# Stripe File Upload with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, stripe-payments

I am still struggling to upload an image to Stripe's servers in order to attach it to an account.

This is my server side code:

```
var accountID = req.body.accountID;
var path = req.body.path;
var name = req.body.name;

stripe.fileUploads.create(
  {
    purpose: 'identity_document',
    file: {
      data: fs.readFileSync(path),
      name: name,
      type: 'application/octet-stream'
    }
  },
  {stripe_account: accountID}
)..//as recommended in the docs
```

This is the attempt to pass over the local path client-side:

```
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
[webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager POST:url.absoluteString
   parameters:@{@"accountID": self.userSnapshot.value[@"accountID"], @"path": localFilePath, @"name": imageName}
     progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
... //results always in error
```

However, I always get errors like this:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices...

I'd be happy if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?